# Build XML tree from Text File in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, tree

I have a text file that show a tree structure. Number of spaces indicate the level for a given member. For example below, Groups can have members or subgroups who can have members and so son:

```
MainGroup
 Member1
 Member2
 Group1
  Member11
  Member12
  Group12
   Member21
   Member22
 Member3
```

Sorry everyone,
My first time and first question here so was figuring out the whole formatting thing.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. I am reading the text file into datatable (This is not necessary but I need the datatable to display the data for me.).
2. Going through each row (has one column), I create a node. I find the number of spaces. If it is zero, I add attributes to this node and add it to doc. If it has spaces, I loop through and keep adding child nodes to this node. That is where things are not working for me.

   ```
   Sub ExportToEXML
       Dim datarow As DataRow
       Dim fileName As String = ""
       Dim level As Integer = 0
       Dim counter As Integer = 0
       Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
       Dim docNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", Nothing)
       doc.AppendChild(docNode)
       Dim ComponentsNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("Components")
       doc.AppendChild(ComponentsNode)

       Dim firstrow As DataRow

       For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
           firstrow = dt.Rows.Item(i)
           fileName = firstrow(0)
           level = CountSpacesBeforeFirstChar(fileName)

           Dim partNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("Component")
           Dim att As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Name")
           att.Value = fileName
           partNode.Attributes.Append(att)
           GetChildNodes(partNode, i, doc, 0, level, dt)
           ComponentsNode.AppendChild(partNode)                   
       Next
       doc.Save("D:\TestXML.xml")    
   End Sub

   Private Sub GetChildNodes(ByRef xNode As XmlNode, ByRef rowInd As Integer, ByRef xDoc As   XmlDocument, level As Integer, table As DataTable)

       Dim lev As Integer
       Dim fileName As String
       Dim dr As DataRow
       For i As Integer = rowInd + 1 To table.Rows.Count - 1
           dr = table.Rows.Item(i)
           fileName = dr(0)
           lev = CountSpacesBeforeFirstChar(fileName)
           If lev = 0 Then 'has no children
               Exit Sub
           End If    

           If lev > level Then
               Dim partNode As XmlNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Component")
               Dim att As XmlAttribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("Name")
               att.Value = fileName
               partNode.Attributes.Append(att)
               xNode.AppendChild(partNode)
               GetChildNodes(xNode, i, xDoc, lev, table)

           End If
       Next        
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you face a problem? Post your code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Number of spaces indicate the level for a given member"? Is it a fixed-width text file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should read the file (if it's not too big read the whole into memory otherwise not), create an empty XML document, iterate through the lines, and depending on the indentation of the line create new Nodes and add them to the appropriate XML element (e.g. keep track of the 'last' node for each level and add them as a child element). Of course you can delay the XML creation to a later phase, and build an object hierarchy based on the file content and simply serialize it when you are done. Or maybe this whole thing can be done with a smart regex. There are quite a few possible solutions.

But frankly: SO is not a place where you will magically get code with no effort. (Well, sometimes it is, but nonetheless: show us you made *some* effort to actually solve the problem before you ask a very general question.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively concise way to do this:

```
Sub ParseHierarchy(ByRef inputFilePath As String, ByRef outputFilePath As String)
    ' We'll treat depth as zero-based to match the number of spaces in the lines
    Dim depth As Integer = -1
    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings
    settings.Indent = True

    Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("testxml.xml", settings)
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(inputFilePath)
            Dim nextDepth As Integer = GetLineDepth(line)

            If nextDepth - depth > 1 Then
                Throw New ApplicationException( _
                    "Depth cannot increase by more than 1 at a time.")
            End If

            '' Close any elements at a deeper or the same depth as the next one
            CloseElements(writer, depth - nextDepth + 1)
            depth = nextDepth

            writer.WriteStartElement("Component")
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", line.Trim())
        Next

        '' Close any elements that are still open
        CloseElements(writer, depth + 1)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub CloseElements(ByRef writer As XmlWriter, ByVal count As Integer)
    For i = 1 To count
        writer.WriteEndElement()
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetLineDepth(line As String) As Integer
    Return Regex.Match(line, "^\s*").Length
End Function
```

When run on your sample file, the output is:

```
<Component Name="MainGroup">
  <Component Name="Member1" />
  <Component Name="Member2" />
  <Component Name="Group1">
    <Component Name="Member11" />
    <Component Name="Member12" />
    <Component Name="Group12">
      <Component Name="Member21" />
      <Component Name="Member22" />
    </Component>
  </Component>
  <Component Name="Member3" />
</Component>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!